# VBA to paste only certain values of cell from one sheet to another

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, cells

Can some one help me with the below code, what I am looking for is, from sheet "Form" certain values of cells mentioned in 2 sets of Array.
1st set of Array should get copied to sheet "Tracker" C3 onward and second set of array from next cell after the 1set of array ends say EF3 onwards.

whereas now first sett is its pasting from A3 and second from A4. Please let me know in case of any question.

Following is the code which I am using now:

```
Sub AddEntry()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, cls
Dim LR2 As Long, j As Long, cls2

cls = Array("C2", "C3", "G2", "G3", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "A17", "C17", "D17", "F17", "G17", "H17", "A18", "C18", "D18", "F18", "G18", "H18", "A19", "C19", "D19", "F19", "G19", "H19", "A20", "C20", "D20", "F20", "G20", "H20", "A21", "C21", "D21", "F21", "G21", "H21", "A25", "B25", "C25", "D25", "E25", "F25", "G25", "H25", "A26", "B26", "C26", "D26", "E26", "F26", "G26", "H26", "A27", "B27", "C27", "D27", "E27", "F27", "G27", "H27", "A28", "B28", "C28", "D28", "E28", "F28", "G28", "H28", "A32", "C32", "E32", "G32", "H32", "A33", "C33", "E33", "G33", "H33", "A34", "C34", "E34", "G34", "H34", "A35", "C35", "E35", "G35", "H35", "A39", "D39", "F39", "A40", "D40", "F40", "A41", "D41", "F41", "A45", "C45", "E45", "G45", "A46", "C46", "E46", "G46", "A47", "C47", "E47", "G47", "D51", "D52", "D53", "D54", "D55", "D56", "D57", "D58", "D59", "D60", "D61", "D62", "D63", "D64", "D65", "D66", "D67")
With Sheets("Tracker")
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(3, .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
        .Cells(LR, i + 1).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(cls(i)).Value
    Next i
End With

cls2 = Array("E51", "E52", "E53", "E54", "E55", "E56", "E57", "E58", "G59", "E60", "E61", "E62", "G63", "E64", "E65", "E66", "E67", "C70", "D70", "E70", "F70", "G70", "H70", "C71", "E71", "G71", "C72", "E72", "G72", "C73", "E73", "G73", "C74", "E74", "G74", "C75", "E75", "G75", "C76", "E76", "G76", "C77", "E77", "G77", "C78", "E78", "G78", "C79", "E79", "G79", "C82", "D82", "E82", "F82", "G82", "H82", "C83", "E83", "G83", "C84", "E84", "G84", "B88", "B89", "B90", "B91", "C88", "C89", "C90", "C91", "D88", "D89", "D90", "D91", "E88", "E89", "E90", "E91", "F88", "F89", "F90", "F91", "G88", "G89", "G90", "G91", "H88", "H89", "H90", "H91")
With Sheets("Tracker")
    LR2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(3, .Range("EW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    For j = LBound(cls2) To UBound(cls2)
        .Cells(LR, j + 1).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(cls2(j)).Value
    Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In the second part of the code, you still reference `LR`, not `LR2`.

Comment: *EF3 onwards*, but you use EW

Comment: I would be interested to see the worksheets because I can almost guarantee that there's a better way to do whatever it is you're doing.  Plus, 215 cells references in 2 arrays, with no apparent pattern, yuck!   :-)

Comment: @JohnyL , sorry for the confusion, but its not working its overlapping the first set of arrays pasted values from A1.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, Hello Robin, But even after chaining the second set of array code to ".Cells(LR2, j + 1).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(cls2(j)).Value" it still overlapping the 1st arrays pasted set from A1. It should get pasted after the 1st set of array. Could you please help??

Comment: @ashleedawg, hello Ashleedawg sure I could send the file to you but I am not getting any option to upload it.

Comment: @Sanoj Use OneDrive or DropBox services

Comment: @ashleedawg here is the link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiK9-yjZAUUwg2oI5zvtrXo3yV5r

Comment: Or I use https://jumpshare.com/

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg I shared with OneDrive :) did you get the shared file??

Comment: Yes, I'll put some ideas in an answer.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to start cell entries in sheet "Tracker" more to the right, you can add the column number instead of +1 (= column A) and write as follows:

**Array 1: assigning cell values starting from column C**

```
   .Cells(LR, i + [C1].Column).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(cls(i)).Value
```

**Array 2: assigning cell values starting from column EF**

```
  ' should be LR2 instead of LR :-)
   .Cells(LR2, j + [EF1].Column).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(cls2(j)).Value
```

**Note**

`[C1].column` returns the column number (in any worksheet), e.g. column C Counts 3.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response works just as I want :) you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your file; the first thing I did was flip through the VBA & *try* to compile it -- which incidentally, I would recommended to anyone as a *first step* with a downloaded `XLSM`.  (I haven't seen a malicious macro yet and I'd like to keep it that way!)

I can see that this file has been a "work in progress" because there are bits of code here and there that don't compile properly, such as `Me` statements pointing to a missing userform, and references to mis-named worksheets such as `Form (View)` instead of `View_Form`.

Ideally, this project should be moved from Excel to Access.  Excel *can* be used for filling forms and storing data, but if this is potentially going to sizable, you're best off to use "the right tool for the job".  Duplicating your form(s) into Access forms instantly removes the need to copy certain cells to certain sheets, not to mention ease of validation, reporting, security, and unlimited room for expansion plus ease of moving data between Excel, Access, Outlook, etc.

(You even called the spreadsheet a database in one spot!)   If your concern is that you're unfamiliar with Access, if you designed this workbook, migration to Access will be a breeze once you figure out the basics of table and form design.

Even Outlook has some pretty nifty form capabilities which can autopopulate the data table when an emailed form is received.

If you need to stay in Excel, how about a User Form instead of the sheet-based form?  I too often see people forgetting about Office's built-in features and starting from scratch.  That being said, I've been a user of MS Office for 25 years and have *never* used an Excel User Form.  **When I think "form", I think MS Access**.

Another option, if you want to stay with the worksheet-based form, instead of listing all the cells in the array etc, a minor redesign could make it simpler. One way would be to have a hidden row on the form tab so you have a single uninterrupted line of all the data you need to store.  For example, you could hide row 1 and 2, make row 1 the headings like `Sourced` `Processed` `Year` `Address` etc. and then row 2 could be an "interim" place to store the data, so A2 formula is `=C2`, B2 is `=C3', B3 is`=C5` etc.

Finally another sneaky option could be to add **hidden comments** in each cell that has data that needs to be saved, and then when the form is complete, loop through all the cells looking for comments, and each comment would contain a title or cell reference indicating where that cell's data needs to go.

The destination should be a very straightforward **table**  Use as many columns as you need, but it's not a place for formatting or formulas.  (Think database!)
For example, `C2` (Sourced By) could have a *hidden* comment like "Tracker:C" then when the form is filled, you could parse the comments and move the data dynamically (instead of hardcoding 250 cell addresses!) with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub moveData() 'untested; example only

    Dim cell As Variant, nextBlankRow As Integer
    Dim comm As String, sht As String, col As String

    nextBlankRow = 5 'calculate this somehow

    'loop through cells with comments
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)

        If cell.Comment.Text <> "" Then
            'get comment
            comm = cell.Comment.Text

            'extract location for data like "Sheetname:Columnletter"
            sht = Left(comm, InStr(comm, ":") - 1)
            col = Right(comm, Len(comm) - InStr(comm, ":"))

            'populate correct location with data
            Sheets(sht).Range(col & nextBlankRow).Value = cell.Value
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

As with anything in Excel (or Office in General) there are a dozen ways you could accomplish the same task.  Opt for the ones that don't involve repeating the same code over and over, nor hardcoded data.  Planning for future (unexpected) growth is very important, as is debugging as-you-go, which is my last suggestion:

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of every module, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>compile often, removing or commenting-out unused code.

Bottom line, best bet: Access, Excel, Outlook all have form capabilities built in.  use a form for a form and you'll save yourself a headache now *and* later.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

***Good Luck!***

Comment: thanks for suggestions but can you share the file as the code you mentioned is way too advanced for me I just started with the codes. Here in our office people are more familiar with Excel.

Comment: Oh I didn't recreate your file, I just checked it out and gave suggestions!  I had assumed that you created the Excel file yourself?  If so, one of the options should be do-able.  If not, well, I could put together a solution in Excel or Access for you in a couple hours...  *for cheap* but not for free!   As for the office being "used to Excel", I've worked in places like that (back when I taught myself how to use Access with only Google as a reference).  A transition to Access would be simpler than you'd think, and it would be a lot easier for the users than an Excel-based form.